# Unable to load C shared library in R

Tags: c++, c, r, rcpp

I am trying to call a `C` code [double_metaphone.c](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rafiot/Fuzzy/master/src/double_metaphone.c) from `R` in windows. I am familiar with R , but have not tried C yet.

I have compiled the code and created a shared library as follows in windows using `Cygwin gcc` including the header file [double_metaphone.h](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rafiot/Fuzzy/master/src/double_metaphone.h)

```
gcc -c double_metaphone.c
gcc -shared -o double_metaphone.dll double_metaphone.o
```

I have used `dyn.load` to load the dll file as follows

```
dyn.load("C:/R/double_metaphone.dll")
```

`getLoadedDLLs()` lists double_metaphone.dll, however

```
is.loaded(double_metaphone.dll)
```

gives the error

```
Error in is.loaded(double_metaphone.dll) : 
  object 'double_metaphone.dll' not found
```

When I try to use `.C()` or `.Call()`, I get

```
Error in .C("double_metaphone") : 
  C symbol name "double_metaphone" not in load table
```

I understand this is a problem with C++ code as in [Link1](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Include-C-DLL-error-in-C-symbol-name-not-in-load-table-td3464021.html), [Link](http://www.lindonslog.com/programming/error-in-c-c-symbol-name-not-in-load-table/), but why can't I access the shared library for calling C code from R? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: If everything else fails, you could consider reading the [fine documentation that came with your copy of R too](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html). In brief, you are doing the compilation wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding "is.loaded" checks for the loaded symbols. As per your header, you can try:

```
is.loaded("DoubleMetaphone")
```

To call the method. try:

```
.C("DoubleMetaphone", <your>, <arguments>)
```

Comment: See my comment to the OP's question. This would work if he had built the shared library correctly, which he didn't.

Answer (score 1):

You need compile and link against `R` for the `shared object` to be loadable. e.g.

```
$ gcc -I/YOUR_R_HOME_DIR/include -DNDEBUG -fpic -c double_metaphone.c -o double_metaphone.o

$ gcc -shared -o double_metaphone.dll double_metaphone.o -L/YOUR_R_HOME_DIR/lib -lR
```

Or simply

```
$ R CMD SHLIB double_metaphone.c
```

As Dirk said, [R-exts](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Creating-shared-objects) gives you more details.

And you want to consider **Rcpp** for writing compiled code in R, which benefits you further down the road.